# Test save method with Mocha in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm writting a basic Mocha test. I try to create a User and save it to the database.

```
var should      = require('should');
var User        = require('../../models/User.js');
require('../utils');

var testAccount = new User({
    local:{
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        password: 'a'
}});

describe('request', function() {
    describe('request', function() {
        it('should create users', function(done) {
            testAccount.save(function(err, user){
                should.not.exist(err);
                done();
            });
        });
        it('should list users', function(done) {
            User.find({}, function(err, users){
                should.not.exist(err);
                users.length.should.equal(1);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

`utils.js` is a simple js file that ensure connection to database

```
var dbURI     = 'dburi';
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var clearDB   = require('mocha-mongoose')(dbURI);

beforeEach(function (done) {
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 0) {
    mongoose.connect(dbURI, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      return done();
    });
  } 
  else {
    return done();
  }
});

afterEach(function (done) {
  mongoose.disconnect();
  return done();
});
```

Mocha don't throw any errors for the `save` method even though it doesn't save the user (I checked also the database). Did I miss anything ?

```
  1 passing (67ms)
  1 failing
  1) request request should list users:
  Uncaught AssertionError: expected 0 to be 1
  + expected - actual
  +1
  -0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm requiring `mocha-mongoose` module that clear database before each test.